I do not understand how we got this inequality in this solution
So this is the problem and solution. I have question about presented solution itself, problem is from 1998 Romanian IMO Team Selection Test if that would be any help, question at the end.
Problem:
Find all positive integers (x, n) such that $x^n + 2^n + 1$
is a divisor of $x^{n+1} + 2^{n+1} + 1$.
Solution:
The solutions are $(x, n) = (4, 1)$ and $(11,1)$. If $n = 1$, we need
$x+3 = x+2+1|x^2 + 4 + 1 = x^2 + 5 = (x + 3)(x − 3) + 14$, so $x + 3$ divides
$14$ and $x = 4$ or $11$. Suppose $n ≥ 2$. For $x ∈ {1, 2, 3}$ we have:
$$1 + 2^n + 1 < 1 + 2^{n+1} + 1 < 2(1 + 2^{n} + 1),$$
$$2^n + 2^n + 1 < 2^{n+1} + 2^{n+1} + 1 < 2(2^n + 2^n + 1), $$
$$2(3^n + 2^n + 1) < 3^{n+1} + 2^{n+1} + 1 < 3(3^n + 2^n + 1)$$
so $x^n+2^n+1$ does not divide $x^{n+1}+2^{n+1}+1$.
For $x ≥ 4$, $$x^n = x^n/2+x^n/2 ≥
2^{2n}/2 + x^2/2$$ so
$$(2^n + 1)x ≤ ((2^n + 1)^2 + x^2)/2$$
$$= (2^{2n} + 2^{n+1} + 1 + x^2)/2 < 2^{n+1} + x^n + 2^n + 2.$$
Therefore:
$$(x − 1)(x^n + 2^n + 1) = x^{n+1} + 2^nx + x − x^n − 2^n − 1$$
$$< x^{n+1} + 2^{n+1} + 1 < x(x^n + 2^n + 1);$$
again $x^n + 2^n + 1$ does not divide $x^{n+1} + 2^{n+1} + 1$. So the only solutions
are (4,1) and (11,1).
Solution Ended
MY QUESTION:
I have question about this inequality, I do not understand how we got it, the one that comes directly after so:
$$(2^n + 1)x ≤ ((2^n + 1)^2 + x^2)/2$$
$$= (2^{2n} + 2^{n+1} + 1 + x^2)/2 < 2^{n+1} + x^n + 2^n + 2.$$
I do not understand how previous thing we wrote after n>=4 was used to get that inequality, I tried googling this exact problem too and I found different solutions but never this one explained more thorougly, so that's why I found it necessary to make this post.

The first inequality is AM-GM inequality $ab\leq(a^2+b^2)/2$ applied to $a=2^n+1$ and $b=x$. I think that where you wrote $(2^n+1)2$ it should be $(2^n+1)^2$.

The second inequality is by using the one after the $x\geq4$. They replace the $2^{2n}/2+x^2/2$ that appear in $(2^{2n}+2^{n+1}+1+x^2)/2$, with $x^n$.

indeed it is supposed to be that, I will correct it right now

OH, that makes sense, I didn't even consider them using $ab\leq(a^2+b^2)/2$, I understand it now, thank you.

is there any way I can mark this solved without there being answer?
